# Event between tabs in wxPython's wx.Notebook

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to create two tabs using wxPython's `wx.Notebook`; however I am having difficulty to understand where I should put the `Bind()` if the button and the ListBox are in different tabs.

Here is how my code looks like: It has class `TabOne`, and `TabTwo`, both of `wx.Panel`. The class `enrollment` is a `wx.Frame` that uses `TabOne`  and `TabTwo` as panels.

```
class TabOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        btn = wx.Button(self, 1, "Add", (120,110))

class TabTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        lst = wx.ListBox(self, 1, (40,40))

class enrollment(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(enrollment, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(panel)

        tab1 = TabOne(nb)
        tab2 = TabTwo(nb)

        nb.AddPage(tab1, "Button")
        nb.AddPage(tab2, "ListBox")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()

        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Show(True)

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    enrollment(None)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ = '__main__':
    main()
```

Just like to know if I want to add a `Bind()` for `btn` in `TabOne` in order to it to update the `ListBox` in `TabTwo`, where should I add the definition for it? I am at a loss at the moment. Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways that you can organize it. **The binding of a button is one thing and the action you take inside the handler is another**. My approach would be to let the `enrollment` class handle binding and the action because it knows about both of the tabs. You would not want to create a dependency between TabOne and TabTwo.

```
class TabOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.btn = wx.Button(self, 1, "Add", (120,110))

    def BindButton(self, handler):
        # let users of TabOne to register their button handler
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, handler)

class TabTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.lst = wx.ListBox(self, 1, (40,40))

    def InformButtonClicked(self):
        # signal to TabTwo about the button click
        self.lst.Append("Item")

class enrollment(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(enrollment, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(panel)

        self.tab1 = TabOne(nb)
        self.tab2 = TabTwo(nb)
        # register your button handler
        self.tab1.BindButton(self.button_handler)

        nb.AddPage(self.tab1, "Button")
        nb.AddPage(self.tab2, "ListBox")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()

        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Show(True)

    def button_handler(self, evt):
        # this method gets called when the button is clicked
        self.tab2.InformButtonClicked()
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and the code! I get it now :D